# I want to display all the page in only 1 windows form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hello I am creating an windows application in which i am having more than one form and I want to display them in to only one windows form like windows operating system i.e. when i click form1.vb than it should be display in same window which currently open. 
I dont know how to implement it please help me. 
Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `multiple document interface`(MDI)
set one form as mdiParent form & remaining forms as mdiChild forms, then when you opens the other forms , they will appear only in MDIparent form area only.

Comment: But i want to make like frame so is it possible to build that using MDI?